# Go to special pages. (using Chromium Browser or Google Chrome command)

Tags: command-line, chromium

I tried:

```
$ chromium-browser chrome://settings/
$ chromium-browser chrome://bookmarks/
$ # etc...
```

And all results is a startup page.

Is there a way to make them work?

Comment: see https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0GT4nCxoM8t0/?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

No.

The developers of that app deliberately made sure it would not for security reasons, as explained at this [Google support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0GT4nCxoM8t0/?hl=en). Many thanks to [cmak.fr](https://askubuntu.com/users/77093/cmak-fr) for finding that.